# Number of possible combinations

Tags: puzzle

How many possible combinations of the variables a,b,c,d,e are possible if I know that:

```
a+b+c+d+e = 500
```

and that they are all integers and >= 0, so I know they are finite.

Comment: That's a neat thing to think about.

Comment: No, a coworker asked me about it because I studied some Probability, but I couldn't solve it

Comment: I assume we're talking integers only here?

Comment: You should clarify the integer restriction in the question.

Comment: Take CSE566 at Ohio State and you'll learn all about this and other counting things. One of my favorite classes.

Comment: If there is no top bound, it's clearly infinite. Even if a, b, and c are zero, you can still just choose d = x and e = -(d - 500) for all values of x >= 500.

Comment: why so many vote downs on the question?

Comment: If one of them is greater than 500, then it's impossible for them to add 500, since none can be negative...

Comment: I just might have to take Michael Haren's advice and walk on down the street to get the answer to this. ;)

Comment: @Kent: Read the part when it says a,b,c,d,e are all greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? I see nothing wrong with puzzles.

Comment: I think a lot of people misread the puzzle.  The "integer" and ">=0" requirements make the puzzle doable.

Comment: Actually, the "integer" and ">=0" requirements make the puzzle difficult.  Without either of those, the answer is easy: infinity!  With those constraints the answer is some finite number

Comment: Does there have to be 5 numbers, or are you interested in solutions with 2-4?

Comment: I'm interested in the solution for 5, but if the other solutions can help me figure it out then they are welcome (the solution for 2 is easy though: 501)

Comment: I gave a solution before for arbitrary numbers of addends and sums.

Comment: Does the order of the variables matter? If it does then that needs to be taken into account in the solution.

Comment: The order matters: The answer should count both 500+0+0+0+0 and 0+0+0+0+50

Comment: In my code below I count the order properly.  That is, all permutations.

Comment: @Chris. I did read that bit. There is no top bound specified, only a lower bound. Hence, any integer can reach positive infinity. Hence, there is an infinite number of permutations. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Torlack, @Jason Cohen: Recursion is a bad idea here, because there are "overlapping subproblems." I.e., If you choose `a` as `1` and `b` as `2`, then you have 3 variables left that should add up to 497; you arrive at the same subproblem by choosing `a` as `2` and `b` as `1`. (The number of such coincidences explodes as the numbers grow.)

The traditional way to attack such a problem is [dynamic programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming): build a table bottom-up of the solutions to the sub-problems (starting with "how many combinations of 1 variable add up to 0?") then building up through iteration (the solution to "how many combinations of *n* variables add up to *k*?" is the sum of the solutions to "how many combinations of *n-1* variables add up to *j*?" with 0 <= *j* <= *k*).

```
public static long getCombos( int n, int sum ) {
  // tab[i][j] is how many combinations of (i+1) vars add up to j
  long[][] tab = new long[n][sum+1];
  // # of combos of 1 var for any sum is 1
  for( int j=0; j < tab[0].length; ++j ) {
    tab[0][j] = 1;
  }
  for( int i=1; i < tab.length; ++i ) {
    for( int j=0; j < tab[i].length; ++j ) {
      // # combos of (i+1) vars adding up to j is the sum of the #
      // of combos of i vars adding up to k, for all 0 <= k <= j
      // (choosing i vars forces the choice of the (i+1)st).
      tab[i][j] = 0;
      for( int k=0; k <= j; ++k ) {
        tab[i][j] += tab[i-1][k];
      }
    }
  }
  return tab[n-1][sum];
}
```

```
$ time java Combos
2656615626

real    0m0.151s
user    0m0.120s
sys 0m0.012s
```

Comment: You're right, dynamic programming is best!  In my code solution above, I suggest using a cache table of pairs, but there's a LOT of pairs, so DP is better.  However I tried to work out the DP solution and it was too hard for little ol' me.  :-)

Comment: Actually just summand * sum pairs, so that's not so bad at 5 x 500.

Comment: @Chris I'm having problems understanding the meaning of values in the array you build in your solution. Could you please give me some example? In your array tab[2][1]=3 and means "how many combinations of (2+1) vars add up to 1? What are these combinations? (I assume that since they are combinations, the order doesn't matter)

Comment: @PiotrekDe "Combinations" is a bad choice of words, copied from the questioner. tab[i][j] is the number of distinct assignments of non-negative integers to i+1 variables such that the variables sum to j. For tab[2][1], let the variables by x, y, z; the assignments are (x=0;y=0;z=1), (x=0;y=1;z=0) and (x=1;y=0;z=0).

Answer (score 5):

**The answer to your question is 2656615626**.

Here's the code that generates the answer:

```
public static long getNumCombinations( int summands, int sum )
{
    if ( summands <= 1 )
        return 1;
    long combos = 0;
    for ( int a = 0 ; a <= sum ; a++ )
        combos += getNumCombinations( summands-1, sum-a );
    return combos;
}
```

In your case, `summands` is 5 and `sum` is 500.

**Note that this code is slow**.  If you need speed, cache the results from `summand,sum` pairs.

I'm assuming you want numbers `>=0`.  If you want `>0`, replace the loop initialization with `a = 1` and the loop condition with `a < sum`.  I'm also assuming you want permutations (e.g. `1+2+3+4+5` plus `2+1+3+4+5` etc).  You could change the for-loop if you wanted `a >= b >= c >= d >= e`.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem for my dad a couple months ago...extend for your use.  These tend to be one time problems so I didn't go for the most reusable...

a+b+c+d = sum

i = number of combinations

```
        for (a=0;a<=sum;a++)
        {
            for (b = 0; b <= (sum - a); b++)
            {
                for (c = 0; c <= (sum - a - b); c++)
                {
                    //d = sum - a - b - c;
                    i++
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

This would actually be a good question to ask on an interview as it is simple enough that you could write up on a white board, but complex enough that it might trip someone up if they don't think carefully enough about it. Also, you can also for two different answers which cause the implementation to be quite different.

**Order Matters**
If the order matters then any solution needs to allow for zero to appear for any of the variables; thus, the most straight forward solution would be as follows:

```
public class Combos {
    public static void main() {
        long counter = 0;

        for (int a = 0; a <= 500; a++) {
            for (int b = 0; b <= (500 - a); b++) {
                for (int c = 0; c <= (500 - a - b); c++) {
                    for (int d = 0; d <= (500 - a - b - c); d++) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Which returns 2656615626.

**Order Does Not Matter**
If the order does not matter then the solution is not that much harder as you just need to make sure that zero isn't possible unless sum has already been found.

```
public class Combos {
    public static void main() {
        long counter = 0;

        for (int a = 1; a <= 500; a++) {
            for (int b = (a != 500) ? 1 : 0; b <= (500 - a); b++) {
                for (int c = (a + b != 500) ? 1 : 0; c <= (500 - a - b); c++) {
                    for (int d = (a + b + c != 500) ? 1 : 0; d <= (500 - a - b - c); d++) {
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
    }
}
```

Which returns 2573155876.

Answer (score 1):

One way of looking at the problem is as follows:

First, a can be any value from 0 to 500.  Then if follows that b+c+d+e = 500-a.  This reduces the problem by one variable.  Recurse until done.

For example, if a is 500, then b+c+d+e=0 which means that for the case of a = 500, there is only one combination of values for b,c,d and e.

If a is 300, then b+c+d+e=200, which is in fact the same problem as the original problem, just reduced by one variable.

Note: As Chris points out, this is a horrible way of actually trying to solve the problem.

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743/number-of-possible-combinations#59833)

Answer (score 0):

If they are a real numbers then infinite ... otherwise it is a bit trickier.

(OK, for any computer representation of a real number there would be a finite count ... but it would be big!)

Comment: They are greater than 0, so not that big

Answer (score 0):

It has general formulae, if
a + b + c + d = N
Then number of non-negative integral solution will be `C(N + number_of_variable - 1, N)`

Answer (score 0):

@Chris Conway answer is correct. I have tested with a simple code that is suitable for smaller sums.

```
                    long counter = 0;
            int sum=25;

            for (int a = 0; a <= sum; a++) {
                for (int b = 0; b <= sum ; b++) {
                    for (int c = 0; c <= sum; c++) {
                        for (int d = 0; d <= sum; d++) {
                             for (int e = 0; e <= sum; e++) {
                           if ((a+b+c+d+e)==sum) counter=counter+1L;

                             }
                       }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("counter e "+counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer in math is 504!/(500! * 4!).

Formally, for x1+x2+...xk=n, the number of combination of nonnegative number x1,...xk is the binomial coefficient: (k-1)-combination out of a set containing (n+k-1) elements.

The intuition is to choose (k-1) points from (n+k-1) points and use the number of points between two chosen points to represent a number in x1,..xk.

Sorry about the poor math edition for my fist time answering Stack Overflow.

`Just a test for code block`

```
Just a test for code block

    Just a test for code block
```

Answer (score -1):

Including negatives? Infinite.

Including only positives? In this case they wouldn't be called "integers", but "naturals", instead. In this case... I can't really solve this, I wish I could, but my math is too rusty. There is probably some crazy integral way to solve this. I can give some pointers for the math skilled around.

being x the end result,
the range of a would be from 0 to x,
the range of b would be from 0 to (x - a),
the range of c would be from 0 to (x - a - b),
and so forth until the e.

The answer is the sum of all those possibilities.

I am trying to find some more direct formula on Google, but I am really low on my Google-Fu today...