# Inference Engine implementation in java

Tags: java, binary, combinations, bit, inference

I am trying to think of an algorithm where I can create number of possible binary combinations for my inference engine implementation

in short if input file to my program has 4 distinct variables my program should be able to generate

0000
0001
0010
.
.
.
1111

combinations.... So far my approach to this problem is as below which is just a thought as it is hard coded at the moment... Basically I need algorithm to generate this for any given number of variable "n".

My Code so far...

```
public class TTAlgorithm {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Integer j = new Integer(10);

        for (int i = 0; i < 4096; i++) {
            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 1) {
                System.out.println("0000000000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 2) {
                System.out.println("000000000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 3) {
                System.out.println("00000000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 4) {
                System.out.println("0000000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 5) {
                System.out.println("000000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 6) {
                System.out.println("00000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 7) {
                System.out.println("0000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 8) {
                System.out.println("000" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 9) {
                System.out.println("00" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 10) {
                System.out.println("0" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }

            if (j.toBinaryString(i).length() == 11) {
                System.out.println("" + j.toBinaryString(i));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Thanks for any help....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work...

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int count = 0;

        int stringSize = 4;
        int maxValue= (int)Math.pow(2, stringSize);

        while(count < maxValue) {
            String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(count);

            while(binaryString.length() < stringSize) {
                binaryString = "0" + binaryString;
            }

            System.out.println(binaryString);
            count++;
        }

    }
```

Output is...

```
0000
0001
0010
0011
0100
0101
0110
0111
1000
1001
1010
1011
1100
1101
1110
1111
```

Put that in a method and have the method take an argument "stringSize" or whatever you want to call it.

Comment: I tried twice...but I can't as I have less than 15 reputation but I will sure once I am above 15...thanks for saving my life lol...happy coding

Comment: +1 Notice how @gshauger has factored out the repetitive part of your code and put it in a loop. He also uses a class reference for the static method `Integer.toBinaryString()`.

Comment: Yeah I read it! it was helpful indeed, And yes I am use to with methods such as Integer.parseInt() but I was try to achieve something but didn't edited my code lol...But I keep that in my mind thanks

Answer (score 1):

See [Incrementing array values - Arduino](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5930005/incrementing-array-values-arduino/5930109#5930109) for an very easy solution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, It was interesting...I might implement it for my other work.